# control flow with IF in mysql request

Tags: mysql

I would like to return a value based on the contents of a column in a mysql table.

example: if 'newsletter' = 1 return "Subscriber" else "not subscribed"

I tried with this syntax :

```
SELECT `id_customer`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `birthday`,
                    CASE WHEN `newsletter`=1 THEN "Abonné" ELSE "Non Abonné" END
                    FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."customer`
                    ORDER BY `lastname` ASC
```

And it does absolutely not work.

A little help please?

Comment: Although it's not plain SQL (`"._DB_PREFIX_."customer`) your approach is correct if the final SQL does not have syntax errors. Unless you say how exactly it's failing to work, we won't be able to provide helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT id_customer, email, firstname, lastname, birthday, 
IF(newsletter=1, "Abonné", "Non Abonné") is_subscribed 
FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."customer ORDER BY lastname ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    id_customer INT(10),
    email VARCHAR(250),
    firstname VARCHAR(100),
    lastname VARCHAR(100),
    birthday DATE,
    newsletter TINYINT(1)
);

INSERT INTO customer (id_customer, email, firstname, lastname, birthday, newsletter)
VALUES (1, 'abe@example.com', 'Abe', 'Aaronson', '1965-12-31', 1),
    (2, 'bill@example.com', 'Bill', 'Bond', '1925-05-01', 0);
```

Your original query (I just got rid of backticks and replaced ANSI quotes with standard quotes and not because they are wrong):

```
SELECT id_customer, email, firstname, lastname, birthday,
CASE WHEN newsletter=1 THEN 'Abonné' ELSE 'Non Abonné' END
FROM customer
ORDER BY lastname ASC;
```

... prints:

```
+-------------+------------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| id_customer | email            | firstname | lastname | birthday   | CASE WHEN newsletter=1 THEN 'Abonné' ELSE 'Non Abonné' END |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|           1 | abe@example.com  | Abe       | Aaronson | 1965-12-31 | Abonné                                                     |
|           2 | bill@example.com | Bill      | Bond     | 1925-05-01 | Non Abonné                                                 |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So you probably have a syntax error somewhere (this appears to be part of a PHP string rather than the final SQL sent to the MySQL server).

I'd also advise to use a column alias. Fechting columns by index is pretty error-prone:

```
... CASE WHEN newsletter=1 THEN 'Abonné' ELSE 'Non Abonné' END AS status
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the IF() function, which is a mysql ternary.  You can alias the result using AS.